# WebVTT: Escape NOTE in subtitle for Firefox 87.0

Tags: webvtt, vtt

In an application I generate Web VTT video subtitle files using input from users and other data sources.

Generally this works fine, but I can't figure out how to show a subtitle line in Firefox starting with the string "NOTE". Example:

```
00:00.000 --> 00:02.000
NOTE A
```

This should show the subtitle "NOTE A" for the first two seconds. In Chromium 89.0 this works fine, but Firefox 87.0 doesn't show anything.

I also can't find a hint for escaping "NOTE" here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API

Comment: Maybe an issue because NOTE is a keyword in vtt. Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/webvtt1/ chapter 1.5 comments. But if I interpret that correctly it should only handle as comment if it is between two subtitles lines. So maybe an issue with Firefox?

Comment: Yes, maybe an issue with Firefox. I created a ticket here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1703444